# Get time-sheet report from JIRA

Tags: jira

I have enabled time-tracking on JIRA, developers are logging time spent. But I can't find a way to get a report on time spent, per-user, over a given period. It saves me asking them to separately send me timesheets to check.

Is it possible? If so where do I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need JIRA TimeSheet Report plugin.
This is in jira 3.x, i'm not sure for jira 4 but you can verify on atlassian's site.
BR
Paul